# Do I still need to use ob_start('mb_output_handler') if I have defined output_handler in PHP configuration?

Tags: php, output-buffering

In my *.htaccess* file I have set the PHP setting `output_handler` like this:

> php_value output_handler mb_output_handler

According to the PHP documentation this will also automatically turn on output buffering. But does it also mean that if I'm calling `ob_start()` within a PHP script, then it will always use the `mb_output_handler` as a callback - **or** do I still need to specifically write `ob_start('mb_output_handler')` every time I want to start a new buffer?

PHP documentation unfortunately doesn't explain in detail what happens if you don't provide a callback function to `ob_start()`...

**UPDATE:**

Or do I even have to set `mb_output_handler` as output handler ***at all*** if everything (input/output/database/script files etc) is in UTF-8? Since `ob_start()` isn't examining or modifying anything in the buffer why do I then have to use `mb_output_handler`?

Comment: It was always a mystery for me why people even use it :-S Why not output in the correct encoding from the very beginning?

Comment: My guess is: Because when ob_start first appeared in PHP it was before there was much attention to character encoding, and in order to be backwards compatible you need to specifically say you want the new better callback function...